# android InMobi + adMob?

Tags: android, admob, ads, inmobi

I want to show InMobi ad in my app. When InMobi ad is not showing (InMobi not success) I want to show adMob ad. How can I check that InMobi is success. Also is showing ad.

I know that Madvertise has a Callbacklistener.

```
 madView = (MadvertiseView) findViewById(R.id.layoutMadView);
 madView.setMadvertiseViewCallbackListener(new MadvertiseViewCallbackListener() {
 @Override 
 public void onLoaded(boolean success, MadvertiseView arg1) {
    if (success) {
       // Madvertise ad
    } else {
       // adMob ad
    }
 }}
```

I tried to change this to InMobi, but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by MAdvertise ? I don't see any official documentation either for this class.

If you want to show ads from multiple providers, you can use [Ad Network Mediation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation). It also allows you to set preference order of advertisers.